# javascript or jquery for multiple forms in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm making an online examination website. We have many forms created by `for` loop in jsp. Each form has 1 multiple choice question and 4 answers.

I wrote a script using `jquery` to check wheter user makes right or wrong that question.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumofQuestions; i++) {
     Question q = (Question) exam.get(i); %>

     <form>
         <p><b>Question <%=i+1%>: </b> <%=q.getContent()%></p>
         <p><b>A. </b><input type="radio" name="answer" value="A"><%=q.getAnswerA()%><br></p>
         <p><b>B. </b><input type="radio" name="answer" value="B"><%=q.getAnswerB()%><br></p>
         <p><b>C. </b><input type="radio" name="answer" value="C"><%=q.getAnswerC()%><br></p>
         <p><b>D. </b><input type="radio" name="answer" value="D"><%=q.getAnswerD()%><br></p>
     </form>

     <span id="result"></span>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $("form").on('click',function() {
             $this = $(this);
             var value = $this.find('input:radio[name=answer]:checked').val();
             var correct = "<%=q.getAnswer()%>";

             if (value == correct) {
                 $('#result').html('right');
             } else { 
                 $('#result').html('wrong');
             }
         });
     </script> 
<% } %>
```

Although the script contains in `for` loop but the variable `correct` always returns the last element of list `exam`. Means `q.getAnswer()` always gets the answer of the last question not the question which is doing. Are there any ways to solve that?

Comment: Better you show the html source generated from browser, I mean, right click and view source.

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct answer to the form as a data attribute if you do not care a view-source will show it. Otherwise you need to ajax to the server to get the answer. $("form") will get ALL forms on the page and you are including jQuery for each and every form in your loop

Alternatively have one form with multiple radios where each set has its own name.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#formContainer").on("click","input:radio[name=answer]", function() {
      var value = this.value, // always the checked value
          $form = $(this).closest("form"),
          correct = $form.data("correct");
      $form.next().html(value == correct ? 'right' : 'wrong');
      $("#score").html($(".result:contains('right')").length);
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="formContainer">
for (int i = 0; i < NumofQuestions; i++) { Question q=( Question) exam.get(i); %>

  <form data-correct="<%=q.getAnswer()%>">
    <p><b>Question <%=i+1%>: </b> 
      <%=q.getContent()%>
    </p>
    <p><b>A. </b>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A">
      <%=q.getAnswerA()%>
        <br>
    </p>
    <p><b>B. </b>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B">
      <%=q.getAnswerB()%>
        <br>
    </p>
    <p><b>C. </b>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C">
      <%=q.getAnswerC()%>
        <br>
    </p>
    <p><b>D. </b>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D">
      <%=q.getAnswerD()%>
        <br>
    </p>
  </form>
  <span class="result"></span>

  <% } %>
</div>
<span id="score"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it works perfectly. But if I want to count how many correct question are there? How can I do that, because if I declare the variable "score" in jquery function, it checks every question not all of questions.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I use a container to gather all clicks on any radio using delegation and count all results containing "right"

Comment: Are there any ways to assign score into a variable? Because when user is doing the test, I will set the span "result" and "score" to hidden and just show the score when user click the submit button. p/s: my apologies because I ask you to much, but I really don't know, thank you again!

Comment: `var score = $(".result:contains('right')").length;`

Comment: Your solutions are good but It's very dangerous because user can see all of the answers by right click and view page source. If I want to have more security, What should I do sir? Thank you.

Comment: "Otherwise you need to ajax to the server to get the answer." Just send the id and answer to the server and return right or wrong: `$form.next().load("check.php?q="+$form.data("id")+"&val="+value)`